# pandas Group by and convert from row of list to column for a large file (No transpose)

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

After using pandas Group by data frame becomes

```
model  item_list
a      [l1,l5,l3,l4,l7,l9,l10]
b      [l2,l6,l1,l5]
c      [l1,l3]
```

And the expected output is

```
model  item_list
    a      l1
    a      l5
    a      l4
    a      l7
    a      l9
    a      l10
    b      l2
    b      l6
    b      l1
    b      l5
    c      l1
    c      l3
```

Is there any approach to get it done with less computation as the actual data is very large?

Please note the original dataframe row item_list consist of []

Comment: Check [maxu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/2901002) answer.

Comment: added new 2 solutions to dupes, maybe better here.

Comment: is there any option while doing in groupby itself? @jezrael

Comment: But why need it? I think it is not necessary. Can you explain more?

Comment: yes actually after doing groupby result is in the form of array. So other solution won't work directly. i have converted it to pandas data frame after groupby but the item list is in the form of array in each row, eg: [l1,l5,l3,l4,l7,l9,l10]  @jezrael

Comment: Can you edit question?

Comment: Edited the question. Sorry for not clearly defining the problem earlier. @jezrael

Comment: hmmm, then use `Maxu` solution, first dupe.

Comment: have tried that too and getting error as explode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'  @jezrael

Comment: Added new dupe, please check it.